# Widget size is reducing while changing the orientation.

Tags: android, widget

While changing the orientation from portrait to landscape my Widget size is reducing. Why this is happening. The widget size I given is 2 x 1.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:minWidth="110dp"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minResizeWidth="144dp"
android:minResizeHeight="64dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/wifi_view"

 />
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because in Lansdscape depending on the device the screen becomes smaller Height wise.

Android re-sizes your widget to fit inside the screen considering other widgets being on the home screen. I dont think there is much you can do about this. This is something Android does automatically.